# Clikable Cell in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation, flutter-container, flutter-table

[Here is the image of my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGxPY.png)

I want to make each cell in 3rd column a clickable Cell that I can navigate from it to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Inkwell(
  onTap: (){},
  child: YourRowWidget()
)
```

Use `inkwell` widget for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add `InkWell` or `GestureDetector` as parent widget of your row. `InkWell` add some visual effect on click. On the other side `GestureDetector` is used on a more general purpose that shows no visual effect/indicator.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () => {},
  child: YourRow(),
),
```

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => {},
  child: YourRow(),
),
```